# Absolute convergence related to Fourier analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, wavelets

If the Fourier transform of a function $f \in L^2$, whose frequency $\xi$ satisfies $|\xi| \leq \pi$,
 has compact support, 
it is famous that
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \sum_n f(n)\frac{\sin\pi(x-n)}{\pi(x-n)}
\end{align*}
holds. However, does this series always converge?
 Daubechies' book "Ten Lectures on Wavelets" says in section 2.1 that this series absolutely converges independent of $x$, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you know whether $\sum_n|f(n)|^2$ converges or not?

Comment: Yes, it certainly converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\operatorname{sinc}$ factor is $O(|n|^{-1})$ and is therefore in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. The first factor, $f(n)$, is also in $\ell^2$, and the conclusion follows from Cauchy-Schwarz.

Actually, $\sum |f(n)|^2<\infty$ for any function with compactly supported Fourier transform (it does not have to be within $|\xi|\le\pi$). Indeed, there is $N$ such that $\operatorname{supp} \hat f\subset I := [- \pi N, \pi N]$. The  functions $\{e^{in\xi}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ on $I$ are mutually orthogonal and have the same $L^2(I)$ norm. Bessel's inequality implies 
$\sum_n |\langle \hat f,e^{in\xi}\rangle|^2<\infty$ which is the desired conclusion.